# Exclude posts that belong to both of two categories

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, categories

I want my homepage to show posts, including from category 16, and category 9, but not shows posts which belong to **both** category 16 and category 9. I'm not sure how to format the query.

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set('cat', array(-16, -9));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

Comment: You can use `$query->set('category__not_in',array(16,9))`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) 
   {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-16,-9' );
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```